# Multiple Docker containers and Celery

Tags: docker, celery

We have the following structure of the project right now:

1. Web-server that processes incoming requests from the clients.
2. Analytics module that provides some recommendations to the users.

We decided to keep these modules completely independent and move them to different docker containers. When a query from a user arrives to the web-server it sends another query to the analytics module to get the recommendations.

For recommendations to be consistent we need to do some background calculations periodically and when, for instance, new users register within our system. Also some background tasks are connected purely with the web-server logic. For this purposes we decided to use a distributed task queue, e.g., Celery.

There are following possible scenarios of task creation and execution:

1. Task enqueued at the web-server, executed at the web-server (e.g., process uploaded image)
2. Task enqueued at the web-server, executed at the analytics module (e.g., calculate recommendations for a new user)
3. Task enqueued at the analytics module and executed there (e.g., periodic update)

So far I see 3 rather weird possibilities to use Celery here:

**I. Celery in separate container and does everything**

1. Move Celery to the separate docker container.
2. Provide all of the necessary packages from both web-server and analytics to execute tasks.
3. Share tasks code with other containers (or declare dummy tasks at web-server and analytics)

This way, we loose isolation, as the functionality is shared by Celery container and other containers.

**II. Celery in separate container and does much less**

Same as **I**, but tasks now are just requests to web-server and analytics module, which are handled asynchronously there, with the result polled inside the task until it is ready.

This way, we get benefits from having the broker, but all heavy computations are moved from Celery workers.

**III. Separate Celery in each container**

1. Run Celery both in web-server and analytics module.
2. Add dummy task declarations (of analytics tasks) to web-server.
3. Add 2 task queues, one for web-server, one for analytics.

This way, tasks scheduled at web-server could be executed in analytics module. However, still have to share code of tasks across the containers or use dummy tasks, and, additionally, need to run celery workers in each container.

What is the best way to do this, or the logic should be changed completely, e.g., move everything inside one container?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

First, let clarify the difference between celery library (which you get with `pip install` or in your `setup.py`) and celery **worker** - which is the actual process that dequeue tasks from the broker and handle them. Of course you might wanna have multiple **workers**/processes (for separating different task to a different worker - for example).

Lets say you have two tasks: `calculate_recommendations_task` and `periodic_update_task` and you want to run them on a separate worker i.e `recommendation_worker` and `periodic_worker`.
Another process will be `celery beat` which just enqueue the `periodic_update_task` into the broker each x hours.

In addition, let's say you have simple web server implemented with [bottle](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/).

I'll assume you want to use celery broker & backend with docker too and I'll pick the recommended usage of celery - [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) as broker and [Redis](https://redis.io/) as backend.

So now we have 6 containers, I'll write them in a `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=vhost
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest
  redis:
    image: library/redis
    command: redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    expose:
      - "6379"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  recommendation_worker:
    image: recommendation_image
    command: celery worker -A recommendation.celeryapp:app -l info -Q recommendation_worker -c 1 -n recommendation_worker@%h -Ofair
  periodic_worker:
    image: recommendation_image
    command: celery worker -A recommendation.celeryapp:app -l info -Q periodic_worker -c 1 -n periodic_worker@%h -Ofair
  beat:
    image: recommendation_image
    command: <not sure>
  web:
    image: web_image
    command: python web_server.py
```

both dockerfiles, which builds the `recommendation_image` and the `web_image` should install celery **library**. Only the `recommendation_image` should have the tasks code because the workers are going to handle those tasks:

**RecommendationDockerfile:**

```
FROM python:2.7-wheezy
RUN pip install celery
COPY tasks_src_code..
```

**WebDockerfile:**

```
FROM python:2.7-wheezy
RUN pip install celery
RUN pip install bottle 
COPY web_src_code..
```

The other images (`rabbitmq:3-management` & `library/redis` are available from docker hub and they will be pulled automatically when you run `docker-compose up`).

Now here is the thing: In you web server you can trigger celery tasks by their string name and pull the result by task-ids (without sharing the code) **web_server.py**:

```
import bottle
from celery import Celery
rabbit_path = 'amqp://guest:guest@rabbit:5672/vhost'
celeryapp = Celery('recommendation', broker=rabbit_path)
celeryapp.config_from_object('config.celeryconfig')

@app.route('/trigger_task', method='POST')
def trigger_task():
    r = celeryapp.send_task('calculate_recommendations_task', args=(1, 2, 3))
    return r.id

@app.route('/trigger_task_res', method='GET')
def trigger_task_res():
    task_id = request.query['task_id']
    result = celery.result.AsyncResult(task_id, app=celeryapp)
    if result.ready():
        return result.get()
    return result.state
```

last file **config.celeryconfig.py**:

```
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'calculate_recommendations_task': {
        'exchange': 'recommendation_worker',
        'exchange_type': 'direct',
        'routing_key': 'recommendation_worker'
    }
}
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['pickle', 'json', 'msgpack', 'yaml']
```

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer!

Comment: You can thank me by accepting the answer and upvote ;-)

Comment: So, basically, I need to reuse the image with code for celery worker containers. If I need to use celery tasks from separate modules, I guess, I should just use different images for each celery container.

Comment: Yes, exctly. You said u want separation between the server and the workers.. but of course you can separate between them as well

Comment: Another question: what if there are 2 modules with different functionality and background tasks and I want these modules to subscribe for particular events that happen on the web server, rather than sending particular tasks to each of them? E.g., new user being added and in one module recommendations are updated and in another module some auxiliary information about this user is fetched. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Sounds like the same question.. maybe add new Question and give more details and I'll try to help

Comment: Great answer - was able to pull up a POC using this without problems.

Comment: Great Answer, one question though. What is the purpose of periodic_worker. I thought recommendation_worker would handle all tasks requested by the web app while the beat container would handle all periodic tasks. You mention beat "enqueues" periodic_update_task which I assume lives in periodic_worker. Is it that beat really only schedules tasks but you need a worker to execute the task? If thats the case why create a seperate container when you could define the beat tasks in recommendation_worker in say a seperate module. Maybe I dont really understand celery beat. Thanks!

Comment: You got that right. The separation is for "encapsulation" and "separation of concerns". Celery provides "beat" command to run its scheduler (blocking process) and the celery worker is also a blocking process. You can tweak them to run in the same docker container but it miss the idea of docker/running small pieces in a sepate containers..