# Celery task.delay blocked in docker container

Tags: django, docker, rabbitmq, celery

I use celery in my Django project. It works well on my MacBook and in a CentOS VM. When I run it in a docker container, the request which contains `add.delay`(`add` is a task) method is always blocked.

I created a demo project on GitHub: https://github.com/fengyouchao/proj_test

My task:

```
@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

My view:

```
def index(request):
    a = int(request.GET.get('a', 1))
    b = int(request.GET.get('b', 2))
    add.delay(a, b)
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")


def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("hello")
```

In the demo project I created three services in docker-compose.yml:

1. web  - The service which run "manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
2. celery - The service which run "celery"
3. rabbitmq - The service which run rabbitmq-server

Run services

```
docker-compose up
```

Test

```
curl localhost:8000 # blocked

curl localhost:8000/hello # OK
```

Run the Django project in current system(use the same rabbitmq-server in docker container)

```
manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:18000
```

Test

```
curl localhost:18000 # OK , and the "celery" service printed task logs
```

This problem has been bothering me for a long time, and I don't know where the problem is. I hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'blocked'? can you attach relevant logs? worker successfully connected to rabbitmq? don't you missed the include param in `Celery` initialization? (with the tasks file)

Comment: "blocked" means that the web server does not respond. Worker has been successfully connected to rabbitmq. I don't think I missed the include param in `Celery` initialization. This problem only occurs when the web are started in docker.

Comment: You can see my answer to another SO question, it might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45863053/multiple-docker-containers-and-celery/45908901#45908901

Answer (score 1):

I just came across a similar issue,

I am using rabbitmq container as a broker so added CELERY_BROKER_URL in `settings.py`

when I run the add.delay() in `manage.py` django shell, inside the container it got struck but works fine in production

So I have added the following change, it started working

```
app = Celery('app', broker="amqp://rabbitmq")
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue, and fixed by it importing the app created on `proj/proj/celery.py` in my `proj/proj/__init__.py` like this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

You can see more information in Celery's [first steps with django](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#django-first-steps) documentation.

Hope it helps!