# Flask web application infinite process on start-up best practices

Tags: python, docker, flask, rabbitmq, celery

I'm working on Flask/Python back-end for web application, which will be deployed with Docker. It's receiving some data from the user, then send it to the RabbitMQ queue. On the other side there're workers in docker containers. The consume task, process and send result back to other RabbitMQ message queue. It works pretty well when I'm running Flask app locally without placing it into docker. What I'm doing - on application start-up I'm running receive thread, which is linked to callback function that consume result from message queue and update note in database. Deploying it with docker and gunicorn as web server, thread is not started with no reason.

How can I run background threads, that would work alongside with Flask web application through the whole web application cycle?

At this moment I'm thinking about next options:

- Try to start thread on application start-up
- Run background task with Celery (cons: after reading a lot of stuff I think Celery is not applicable here because it mostly using for task that could be finished in the upcoming future. I could be wrong. If yes, please correct me).
- Flask module called app_scheduler. I've used it just couple times and I think Celery is better in this case.

My web app structure is pretty simple:

```
app.py
models.py
app
 |-engine - # classes Send and Receive, function run_receive()
 |-tasks
     |-__init__.py
     |-routes.py
     |-tools.py
     |-email.py
 |-templates
 |-__init__.py # create_app() function here
```

My `create_app()` function from the `app/__init__.py` file.

```
def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app_ = Flask(__name__)
    app_.config.from_object(config_class)
    # extensions
    db.init_app(app_)
    migrate.init_app(app_, db)
    celery.init_app(app_)
    mail.init_app(app_)
    # blueprints
    from app.engine import bp as bp_engine, run_receive
    from app.tasks import bp as bp_tasks

    app_.register_blueprint(bp_engine)
    app_.register_blueprint(bp_tasks)

    ...
```

So what I want to do is on start-up run thread which will consume results from RabbitMQ. Function for this action is called `run_receive()` and is placed in the `app/engine/__init__.py`.

Also in the future I'd like to run another thread to check whether notes in the database are out-of-date. So it would be another thread, that would be invoked every day to check database.

So what are the best practices in this situation?

Thank you for your response.

Comment: Use Celery or Dramatiq. They are made for such tasks!

Comment: Thank for your response. Where could I define celery task and in what moment should I run this task to run only one Celery task per server in multi-threading web server?

Comment: You can spawn a one celery worker per server, and only 1 task will be executed at a time. But I am not sure why do you need threads in the application.

Comment: I'm sorry, i meant multiprocessing. By default celery works as multiprocessing server. It starts with a single process and then get forked.

Comment: I've typically seen a Celery worker launched as a separate container.

Comment: @DavidMaze could you show any example?

Comment: [Multiple Docker containers and Celery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45863053/multiple-docker-containers-and-celery) has a pretty good example: you can build an image with all of the required code bundled in, and launch a second container with the same `image:`, but a different Compose `command:` that starts the Celery worker.