# Using different Redis databases for different queues in Celery

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, worker

I have a **Django** application that uses **Celery** with **Redis** broker for asynchronous task execution. Currently, the app has **3 queues** (& 3 workers) that connect to a single Redis instance for communication. Here, the first two workers are **prefork-based** workers and the third one is a **gevent-based** worker.

The Celery setting variables regarding the broker and backend look like this:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL="redis://localhost:6379/0"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND="redis://localhost:6379/1"
```

Since Celery uses [rpush-blpop](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/a192f9cbf546e36b590166426d5e26a90964eeb1/t/integration/tasks.py#L211) to implement the FIFO queue, I was wondering if it'd be correct or even possible to use different Redis databases for different queues like — q1 uses database `.../1` and q2 uses database `.../2` for messaging? This way each worker will only listen to the dedicated database for that and pick up the task from the queue with less competition.

- Does this even make any sense?
- If so, how do you implement something like this in Celery?

Comment: why did you choose Redis as the broker and not RabbitMQ? what's the load it is supposed to handle?

Comment: Mostly simplicity. Celery Redis config seemed dead-simple to me and I just picked that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you are worried about the load, please specify your expected numbers/rates.

In my opinion, you shouldn't be concerned about the Redis capability to handle your load.

1. Redis has its own scale-out / scale-in capabilities whenever you'll need them.
2. You can use RabbitMQ as your broker (using [rabbitMQ docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq) is dead-simple as well, you can see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45863053/multiple-docker-containers-and-celery/45908901#45908901)) which again, has its own scale-out capabilities to support a high load, so I don't think you should be worried about this point.

As far as I know, there's no way to use different DBs for Redis broker. You can create different Celery applications with different DBs but then you cannot set dependencies between tasks (canvas: group, chain, etc). I wouldn't recommend such an option.