# connection refused: Celery-RabbitMQ

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I am integrating celery with FastAPI. I am using rabbitmq as a broker with celery. When ever I submit task to celery I get this error: "kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: [Errno 111] Connection refused". I don't understand maybe its due to the connection with rabbitmq but when I start the celery worker, It didn't give any connection error, but at the time of task submission.
Following is my code:
main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from scraper import crawl_data
from task import sample_task

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/test")
def test():
    data = sample_task.delay()
    return {'MESSAGE': 'DONE'}
```

task.py

```
from celery_config import app
import time


@app.task
def sample_task():
    for i in range(1, 10):
        time.sleep(10)
    print("DONE TASK")
```

celery_config.py

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('celery_tutorial',
             broker="amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//",
             include=['task'])
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  main_app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: fastapi.Dockerfile
    command: uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --reload
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8-management-alpine
    ports:
      - 15673:15672

#  celery_worker:
#    build:
#      context: .
#      dockerfile: fastapi.Dockerfile
#    command: celery -A celery worker --loglevel=info
#    depends_on:
#      - rabbitmq
#      - main_app

    stdin_open: true
```

I start the FastAPI server and rabbitmq with docker compose, and celery worker with following command:

```
celery -A celery_config worker --loglevel=info
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `celery_config.py` run within the `main_app` container, the broker's host should be `rabbitmq` (service name) rather than localhost:

```
app = Celery('celery_tutorial',
             broker="amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672/vhost",
             include=['task'])
```

**EDIT**:

seems like you didn't set the relevant env vars:

```
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8-management-alpine
    ports:
      - 15673:15672
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=vhost
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest
```

make sure you add them, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45908901/1011253).

Comment: it says "ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@rabbitmq:5672//"

Comment: @usama97 edit my answer for you (see `vhost` in the `Celery` creation as well)