# Can't install supervisor in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, centos, supervisord

I have a Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10.4

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor 

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .
COPY ./docker/api/conf.d/supervisor.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8010
CMD ["uvicorn", "v1.api:app", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port", "8010", "--reload"]
```

When I build this Dockerfile on my local machine (Ubuntu), everything works fine
However, when I build it on a CentOS 7 virtual machine, i got this error:

> => ERROR [3/7] RUN apt-get install -y supervisor
> 0.6s
>
> ---
>
> ### [3/7] RUN apt-get install -y supervisor:
> #0 0.473 Reading package lists...
> #0 0.501 Building dependency tree...
> #0 0.503 Reading state information...
> #0 0.508 E: Unable to locate package supervisor
>
> failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y supervisor]: exit code: 100

Please help me.

How do I install supervisor in the container

Comment: (Do you actually need it?  The Dockerfile as you show it doesn't seem to use it, and in general running multiple single-process containers is a more scalable and maintainable pattern than trying to use supervisord to run multiple processes in one container.)

Comment: @DavidMaze yes I do need to use supervisor. I'm having 2 python files that are used to listening to 2 different message queues (RabbitMQ). And this is my current solutions to do it since the app container (above Dockerfile) already installed all of the python packages, so I won't need to install it again on another container to use supervisor

Comment: That seems like a very routine case of running two containers with the same image but different commands.  [Multiple Docker containers and Celery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45863053/multiple-docker-containers-and-celery/45908901#45908901) includes an example of launching a Flask server and two separate Celery workers, in sparate containers, all from the same image.